# Git error when installing brew on mac monterey (m1)

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

I've checked many many topics and tried many scripts without success.

After executing this

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

I get this error

`==> Downloading and installing Homebrew... git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.  Failed during: git fetch --force origin`

I have no idea how to fix it. Worth mentioning that I can clone other repos, the git command works.

Any idea?

The user name and email are already configured on git, also the xcode tools. I deleted all the previous (failed) homebrew installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the git version 2.38.0 has something broken.

I've updated the git using the **mac ports** and now it worked with version 2.38.1